# using variable in mysql join query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

In this query when i place value of   cities.city_id   manually it works fine but when i pass with a variable like  $adcity   it not showing any output. can any one help me how to use variable in this query.

can some one help me in this regard.

```
$sql = 'SELECT advertisments.ad_id,
         advertisments.ad_title, 
        advertisments.ad_title_slug,
         advertisments.ad_type, 
        advertisments.last_date,
         organizations.organization_logo, 
        cities.city_id, 
        cities.city_name, 
        newspapers.newspaper_logo, 
        newspapers.newspaper_name
FROM advertisments, organizations, cities, newspapers
WHERE advertisments.organization_id = organizations.organization_id
AND advertisments.city_id = cities.city_id
AND advertisments.newspaper_id = newspapers.newspaper_id
AND ad_type = "Admissions"
AND cities.city_id = "$adcity"
        ORDER BY ad_id DESC 
        LIMIT 10';
        $open_admissions = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: first run your query in phpmyadmin or in cpanel. Check if it returns some rows or not

Comment: @AghaUmairAhmed thanks let me check it there.

Comment: You are using pretty old and insecure syntax. Consider using MySQLi.

Comment: what does "or die(mysql_error()) give you - and note that this suite of functions (mysql_) is deprecated

Comment: And use explicit JOIN syntax instead of this comma-join stuff (and it's "advertisEment"!)

Comment: You are using a single quoted string (`'`) which does **not evaluate php code/variables**. That means your `$adcity` will not evaluate to a variable, but to text saying `$adcity` instead of a number. These are basics of PHP. And as others have said, you're using an extremely outdated approach to interacting with MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you try.

```
$sql = 'SELECT advertisments.ad_id,
         advertisments.ad_title, 
        advertisments.ad_title_slug,
         advertisments.ad_type, 
        advertisments.last_date,
         organizations.organization_logo, 
        cities.city_id, 
        cities.city_name, 
        newspapers.newspaper_logo, 
        newspapers.newspaper_name
FROM advertisments, organizations, cities, newspapers
WHERE advertisments.organization_id = organizations.organization_id
AND advertisments.city_id = cities.city_id
AND advertisments.newspaper_id = newspapers.newspaper_id
AND ad_type = "Admissions"
AND cities.city_id = "'.$adcity.'"
        ORDER BY ad_id DESC 
        LIMIT 10';
        $open_admissions = mysql_query($sql);
```

Just add. `cities.city_id = "'.$adcity.'"` like this.

Hope it will works for u. If it is not working. Inform me.

Thanks

Comment: Shamsher Kaim k  thank you for your kind help, i already resolved my issue but you commented same solution so accepting it.